# Using the transition matrix for computing probability.

Tags: probability

Ruth has a red coin, and Ben has a blue coin. The red coin has a probability of $p$ for heads, and the blue coin has a probability of $q$ for heads. They play a game: they both toss their coins, and if both coins show "Heads" they switch the coins. Otherwise, they keep them. Let $A_n$ denote the event in which Ben has the blue coin after $n$ rounds. Find $P(A_2),P(A_3)$.

There are two situations: Ruth=red, Ben=blue with probability of $pq$ to change it and a probability of $1-pq=p(q-1)+q(p-1)$ to keep it that way. The same goes for the other situation. I get: $P=\begin{pmatrix}1-pq&pq\\pq&1-pq\\ \end{pmatrix}$. But how do I use it to compute actual probabilities? I guess I am to use matrix multiplication but I will have to understand how I turn a matrix into a number. I could really use your help.

Comment: Do you insist on a method involving matrices?

Comment: I did it without matrices, but the third question is "find four values of the vector $(p,q)\in[0,1]^2$" such that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}{P(A_n)}$ exists, and I guess I better use something easier to get $P(A_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_0=\left( \array{ 1 \\ 0 }\right)$. This first entry is the probability that Ben has the blue coin at time 0, while the 2nd entry is that Ben has the red coin at time 0.

Now, convince yourself that

$v_1=\left( \array{ 1-pq & pq \\ pq & 1-pq}\right)\left( \array{ 1 \\ 0 }\right)$
Is the probability distribution of Ben having the blue coin after 1st toss

Prove by induction that $v_{n}:=A^nv_0$ is the distribution of ben having the blue/red coin after $n$ tosses. That is:

$v_n=\left(\array{P(A_n)\\ 1-P(A_n)}\right).$

To find the limit distribution in the comments i provide a hint: Try any combination of $p,q\in (0,1)$ and diagonalize the matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by trying any combination?

Comment: as i understood your comment; You need to find 4 specific vectors (p,q) where the limit exists. All i'm saying is that you can choose any p,q not being 1 or 0.

Comment: Should I diagonalize using eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes. You will find that $A$ has an eigenvalue =1, and an eigenvalue <1. 

You can then use $A=VDV^{-1}$ to find a simply expression for $A^n$. This enables you to find the desired limit

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} v_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A^n v_0$